# How to produce Sratic RAM using 10nM technology

Tags: electronics

If I want to produce 2GB SRAM module using 10nM or smaller than 10nM technology, what should I do?

Please state step by step and also how much would it be?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic this probably wouldn't be well received on EE, if it's a practical problem the answer would probably be to contact someone like Intel or Samsung for a quote (which would no doubt run into the millions). If it's a general interest or homework question it's really very broad, IMO it really needs more clarification to be a good fit on any SE site.